# PHP - Save image on exit/reload page - Server side

Tags: javascript, php, svg, save

I've got a question. I've been google-ing for a few hours now :)

**Background info:** 
I've got a Javascript that draws and creates a SVG. I've found a function that creates a download link for the client side (code below) And this works fine. But I want this different.

**The Question:** How can I save this SVG on page exit/reload on the server side?

This was the code I've used for a client side save button:

```
   var downloadAsSVG = function (fileName) {

   if(!fileName) {
       fileName = "example.svg"
   }

   var url = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + encodeURIComponent(mySvg.getSerializedSvg(true));

   var link = document.createElement("a");
   link.download = fileName;
   link.href = url;
   document.body.appendChild(link);
   link.click();
   document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

Now this piece in JS grabs my SVG using "canvas2svg":

```
    mySvg.getSerializedSvg(true)
```

I can imagine this is not possible using pure JS, keeping security in mind.

Comment: the same way u create link, use to create <img /> tag and provide that url to its source property "src". i guess it should work

Comment: where do you want to save the image? on the server or on the client?

Comment: @HolgerWill I want to save it to the serverside. Say, to the image folder. The script above is more to test the 'getSerialedSvg()' command.

Comment: I guess this question has two layers. 1. How to run a script at exiting/reloading the page. And 2. how to save the svg to the server. And in what language? php/javascript/ajax? The svg exists inside a javascript var. And is not displayed on the page.

Comment: Posting the string to the server is easy.  I would not rely on running the script on exit. Exits are not always controled ( crash, power outage, buggy network, empty battery... whatever) so I would save on every change. You could even save local in localStorage and then synchronize with the sever based on some timestamp... what server tech are you using?

Comment: I'm listening :)            Server tech as-in specs? I can switch betweeen php 5.3, 5.4, 5.5 and. 5.6 and PHP memory limit:  96 MB, max. 512 MB.            The syncing might be interesting! Maybe delete the current older version after successful sync. :)

Comment: @HolgerWill, how would I be doing this? I've looked for stuff like this. But they all need ftp. I think I'm looking in the wrong direction with this :)

Comment: i can not help with php (i'm coding node.js mostly...), if you like i can add an answer outlining how to code the client side though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## YES!!

Finally did it. I've combined multiple answers found on stackoverflow

## 1

JS - this function sends the data to the save php

```
    var exportAsSVG = function (fileName) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","savefile.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("svgData="+rttSvg.getSerializedSvg(true));
    }
```

## 2

php - this is the save file.php

```
    <?php
    $post_data = $_POST['svgData'];
    if (!empty($post_data)) {
    $dir = 'images/';
    //$file = 'test';
    $file = date('Y-m-d-G-i-s');
    $filename = $dir.$file.'.svg';
    $handle = fopen($filename, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $post_data);
    fclose($handle);
    echo $file;
    }
    ?>
```

## 3

JS - this gets run when you refresh or leave the page.

```
       window.onbeforeunload = function(){
       exportAsSVG();
    }
    // OR
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e){
       exportAsSVG();
    }, false);
```

## 4

Next step I’ll look on how to implement te local storage option for the auto save function.
For this I’ll also move the filename / time stamp to the main file as reference.

many many thanks on your help @holger!

Answer (score 0):

on the client you can use the fairly new [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to post your data here i post it as json to a json consuming endpoint

```
var data = new FormData();
    data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( {svg: mySvg.getSerializedSvg(true) } ) );

    x= fetch("/some/json/consuming/url",{
          method: "POST",
          body: data
       })
       .then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
       .then(function(data){ alert( JSON.stringify( data ) ) })
```

on the client its much simpler... saving it

```
localStorage.setItem("mysvg", mySvg.getSerializedSvg(true));
```

and loading it

```
var url = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + encodeURIComponent(localStorage.getItem("mysvg"));;
```

is just one line of code.

if you want to stay on the client (scripting wise), but still want to save to a server you might have a look at [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)

Comment: Hi @holger, Great, thanks! I'll look into it! looks promising!